# how to display images in gridview using c# in windowsform from imagepath stored in sql database

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

How to display images in gridview using C# from ImageUrl stored in sql 2008 database. Images are stored in C:\ProjectFolder\Images

My grid has 1 text column and 4 image columns and database table structure is also same.
Have tried this and this is showing same images in two rows:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("image path");
DataGridViewImageColumn ImageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
ImageColumn.Image = image;
ImageColumn.Name = "Name";
ImageColumn.HeaderText = "Nice Name";
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, ImageColumn);
```

Comment: DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
System.Drawing.Image image1 = default(System.Drawing.Image);
for (int a = 0; a < dgvDisplayImages.Rows.Count - 1; a++)
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ImageID,ImageCatName,ImageName,ImageTexture1,ImageTexture2,ImageTexture3,ImageTexture4,ImageTexture5,ImageTexture6,ImagePath from ImageTable", obj.GetConnection());
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (sdr.Read())
{
image1 = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + dr[3].ToString());
img.Image = image1;
dgvDisplayImages.Rows[a].Cells[3].Value = image1;
}
}

Comment: We want to retrieve image from saved image path in database. We have tried both ways:1. Adding columns dynamically and 2. Already created Image columns. But unable to insert/ display the images in specified imagecolumns.

Answer (score 0):

Image image = Image.FromFile("image path");
**applies default image for that column.**

**For chaanging image on particular row and column you should write**

int rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value = Image.FromFile("image path");//for first image column

dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = Image.FromFile("image path");//for second image column

dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Value = Image.FromFile("image path");//for third image column

dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Value = Image.FromFile("image path");//for forth image column

Comment: Numbers of rows are not fixed. Today 100 rows are there after 10 days may be 500 rows will be there. Therefore I think, foreach loop should be used here to fetch all rows from databasetable. But dont know how to implement that.